# elastic search using floating point

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, kibana

I am new to Kibana. I am doing some search in 'Discover' and plotting them in 'Visualize'. For a task, I need to filter out a field that is floating-point. However, when I search using the floating-point in discover, kibana returns no result.

For example:

```
my_field: <= 6.66
```

then there is no result. However, if I search with integer value like

```
my_field: <= 6
```

Only then I get a search results. However,  my_field has floating-point values in the returned result.

So my question is how can I search using floating-point value in kibana ?

Edit:
If I type `GET master.bckup_v8/_mapping`  then I get:

```
"my_field" : {
            "type" : "float"
          },
```

And kibana search bar looks like the below figure:
[kibana search bar screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4JXij.png)

Options bar options:
[options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qdfQg.png)

Additionl info:
searching using query: `my_field:[* TO 6.66]` throws error:

```
Discover: Can only use prefix queries on keyword and text fields - not on [peakSpeed] which is of type [float]
```

The query `my_field:<=6` from inspect:

```
GET /_search
{
  "version": true,
  "size": 10000,
  "sort": [
    {
      "timestamp": {
        "order": "desc",
        "unmapped_type": "boolean"
      }
    }
  ],
  "_source": {
    "excludes": []
  },
  "aggs": {
    "2": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "timestamp",
        "interval": "3h",
        "time_zone": "Europe/Berlin",
        "min_doc_count": 1
      }
    }
  },
  "stored_fields": [
    "*"
  ],
  "script_fields": {},
  "docvalue_fields": [
    {
      "field": "ingestionTime",
      "format": "date_time"
    },
    {
      "field": "timestamp",
      "format": "date_time"
    }
  ],
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "query_string": {
            "query": "my_field: <= 6",
            "analyze_wildcard": true,
            "default_field": "*"
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "timestamp": {
              "gte": 1606777200000,
              "lte": 1607435332914,
              "format": "epoch_millis"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "filter": [],
      "should": [],
      "must_not": []
    }
  },
  "highlight": {
    "pre_tags": [
      "@kibana-highlighted-field@"
    ],
    "post_tags": [
      "@/kibana-highlighted-field@"
    ],
    "fields": {
      "*": {}
    },
    "fragment_size": 2147483647
  }
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225715/discussion-on-question-by-tokai-elastic-search-using-floating-point).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the issue you're suffering from is documented [here](https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/59501). It can be solved by going to "Management > Advanced Settings" in Kibana and then by adding the following to the `query:queryString:options` configuration

```
"lenient": true
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Val. Specially for the patience to take me to the path of solution :))

Answer (score 0):

At first your query is not valid. you should remove the :

```
my_field <= 6.66
```

If it does not work, your field is probably mapped as an integer (long ?) and not as a float.

You should probably read the basic documentations on elasticsearch and kibana to understand the basic concepts and the differents functionalities.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wAjuLb48xCU
https://medium.com/@sami.jan/fundamentals-of-elasticsearch-cbb273160f60

Comment: I think this a mapping problem like mentioned by Val. But query using `:` sign should be fine. It works. I have also seen example[link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html)